# NSOpenGLView drops its NSOpenGLContext on macOS 10.9

Tags: macos, nsopenglview

The `NSOpenGLView` class has a read/write property `openGLContext`, and as I read the documentation, the getter should never return nil:

> If the receiver has no associated context object, a new `NSOpenGLContext` object is created. The new object is initialized with the receiver’s pixel format information.

On macOS 10.13, that seems to be true, but on macOS 10.9, it returns nil after I add the view to a window.  That is, if I do this:

```c
NSOpenGLView* glView = [[NSOpenGLView alloc]
    initWithFrame: NSMakeRect( 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0 )
    pixelFormat: [NSOpenGLView defaultPixelFormat]];
NSLog(@"Pixel format %@, context %@", glView.pixelFormat, glView.openGLContext );

[self.host addSubview: glView];
NSLog(@"Pixel format %@, context %@", glView.pixelFormat, glView.openGLContext );
```

Then on the second log, the context is nil.  Is there any fix?  Making my own `NSOpenGLContext` and assigning it doesn't help.  I have verified that the host view is part of a window and that the `windowNumber` is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, in Mavericks one must set the view of the context as well as setting the context of the view.  Something like this works:

```c
NSOpenGLPixelFormat* pf = [NSOpenGLView defaultPixelFormat];

NSOpenGLView* glView = [[[NSOpenGLView alloc]
    initWithFrame: NSMakeRect( 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0 )
    pixelFormat: pf] autorelease];

NSOpenGLContext* glc = [[[NSOpenGLContext alloc]
    initWithFormat: glView.pixelFormat shareContext: nil] autorelease];

[self.host addSubview: glView];

glc.view = glView; // the key step I was missing
glView.openGLContext = glc;
NSLog(@"Pixel format %@, context %@", glView.pixelFormat, glView.openGLContext );
```